# How to make generic test for corporate network availability?

Tags: bash, intranet

As I work remotely I do often have to run scripts that make sense only when I am on intranet.

But I a not always connected to intranet and I would prefer to define a more generic way of testing the connectivity so I bypass when I am not in "work-mode" ;)

I to implement this as a simple bash command or script so I can do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
is-intranet-on || echo "Yeah, time to do something!"
```

If I do this I will be include this even on `crontab` so I can have scheduled tasks that run only when connected to intranet.

I need to make this work on both MacOS and Linux. Currently I use OpenVPN but I think that testing for network interfaces would be the wrong approach because: I could configure the VPN on my router or I could be in the office.

My impression is that the final solution would have to involve some kind of DNS check, but I need to make it kinda safe as I don't want surprised from captive portals that may return me fake IP for a DNS entry.

Comment: may be better suited for https://superuser.com/ than here?

Comment: @Inian I am looking for some code and SO seems much better suited... I am sure this cannot be solved by configuring something. Probably I will post the solution myself in few hours, that's what I end-up doing when "outsourcing" to SO doesn't give a quick solution ;)

Comment: The main question is: how do you know that you are connected to the intranet. That may be a ping to a specific server, a wget/curl and verification of the output etcetera. the code thereafter is trivial; for example: `ping -c1 10.10.10.10 && echo "I'm on intranet"`

Comment: I think that best bet is to check if a DNS address is resolving, or even better to see if a HTTPS head request succeeds. HTTPS would solve the problem of captive portals.

Comment: Use `ping` for a host that is only reachable when the Intranet is up. Cron the command to run every minute and send yourself an email when you have a successful `ping` reply. If you want to take it further, then create a suitable audio alert on your mobile phone for emails that are filtered.

Answer (score 0):

If for example you know that you have a server named `example.intra` and the name is only resolvable within the intranet or on VPN, and lets say the name resolves to `10.1.1.3` and the machine is pingable, the code would simply be something like:

```
is_intranet_on() {
    [[ $(dig example.intra +short) == "10.1.1.3" ]] && ping -c 1 example.intra &> /dev/null
}
```

Which checks that the dns name resolves to a specific ip and then pings the ip to make sure there is at least some kind of network connectivity.

The output will be return code 0 when there is connectivity and return code 1 when there is none. You can put this function in your script, or source it.

You could modify this to use curl instead to check for a https-site by first obtaining the certificate-chain from your server with something like:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername example.intra -connect example.intra:443 > cacert.pem
```

This command saves the certs into a file named `cacert.pem`

And then using curl to check that the server is ok using the certificates:

```
[[ $(curl -s -I -L -m 4 --cacert cacert.pem https://example.intra | head -n 1) == "HTTP/1.1 200 OK" ]]
```

Change the string `HTTP/1.1 200 OK` to whatever your server responds if needed (for example a `204` status or whatever)